# Number of Comparisons in Merge-Sort

Tags: algorithm, merge, complexity-theory, mergesort

I was studying the merge-sort subject that I ran into this concept that the number of comparisons in merge-sort (in the worst-case, and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)) equals (n ⌈lg n⌉ - 2<sup>⌈lg n⌉</sup> + 1); in fact it's between (n lg n - n + 1) and (n lg n + n + O(lg n)). The problem is that I cannot figure out what these complexities try to say. I know O(nlogn) is the complexity of merge-sort but the number of comparisons?

Answer (score 8):

## Why to count comparisons

There are basically two operations to any sorting algorithm: comparing data and moving data. In many cases, comparing will be more expensive than moving. Think about long strings in a reference-based typing system: moving data will simply exchange pointers, but comparing might require iterating over a large common part of the strings before the first difference is found. So in this sense, comparison might well be the operation to focus on.

## Why an exact count

The numbers appear to be more detailed: instead of simply giving some Landau symbol (big-Oh notation) for the complexity, you get an actual number. Once you have decided what a basic operation is, like a comparison in this case, this approach of actually counting operations becomes feasible. This is particularly important when comparing the constants hidden by the Landau symbol, or when examining the non-asymptotic case of small inputs.

## Why this exact count formula

Note that throughout this discussion, lg denotes the logarithm with base 2. When you merge-sort *n* elements, you have ⌈lg *n*⌉ levels of merges. Assume you place ⌈lg *n*⌉ coins on each element to be sorted, and a merge costs one coin. This will certainly be enough to pay for all the merges, as each element will be included in ⌈lg *n*⌉ merges, and each merge won't take more comparisons than the number of elements involved. So this is the *n*⌈lg *n*⌉ from your formula.

As a merge of two arrays of length *m* and *n* takes only *m* + *n* − 1 comparisons, you still have coins left at the end, one from each merge. Let us for the moment assume that all our array lengths are powers of two, i.e. that you always have *m* = *n*. Then the total number of merges is *n* − 1 (sum of powers of two). Using the fact that *n* is a power of two, this can also be written as 2<sup>⌈lg *n*⌉</sup> − 1, and subtracting that number of returned coins from the number of all coins yields *n*⌈lg *n*⌉ − 2<sup>⌈lg *n*⌉</sup> + 1 as required.

If *n* is 1 less than a power of two, then there are ⌈lg *n*⌉ merges where one element less is involved. This includes a merge of two one-element lists which used to take one coin and which now disappears altogether. So the total cost reduces by ⌈lg *n*⌉, which is exactly the number of coins you'd have placed on the last element if *n* were a power of two. So you have to place fewer coins up front, but you get back the same number of coins. This is the reason why the formula has 2<sup>⌈lg *n*⌉</sup> instead of *n*: the value remains the same unless you drop to a smaller power of two. The same argument holds if the difference between *n* and the next power of two is greater than 1.

On the whole, this results in the formula given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort):

> *n* ⌈lg *n*⌉ − 2<sup>⌈lg *n*⌉</sup> + 1

*Note: I'm pretty happy with the above proof. For those who like my formulation, feel free to distribute it, but don't forget to attribute it to me as the [license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) requires.*

## Why this lower bound

To proove the lower bound formula, let's write ⌈lg *n*⌉ = lg *n* + *d* with 0 ≤ *d* < 1. Now the formula above can be written as
*n* (lg *n* + *d*) − 2<sup>lg *n* + *d*</sup> + 1 =
*n* lg *n* + *nd* − *n*2<sup>*d*</sup> + 1 =
*n* lg *n* − *n*(2<sup>*d*</sup> − *d*) + 1 ≥
*n* lg *n* − *n* + 1
where the inequality holds because 2<sup>*d*</sup> − *d* ≤ 1 for 0 ≤ *d* < 1

## Why this upper bound

I must confess, I'm rather confused why anyone would name *n* lg *n* + *n* + O(lg *n*) as an upper bound. Even if you wanted to avoid the floor function, the computation above suggests something like *n* lg *n* − 0.9*n* + 1 as a much tighter upper bound for the exact formula. 2<sup>*d*</sup> − *d* has its minimum (ln(ln(2)) + 1)/ln(2) ≈ 0.914 for *d* = −ln(ln(2))/ln(2) ≈ 0.529.

I can only guess that the quoted formula occurs in some publication, either as a rather loose bound for this algorithm, or as the exact number of comparisons for some other algorithm which is compared against this one.

---

## (Two different counts)

*This issue has been resolved by the comment below; one formula was originally quoted incorrectly.*

> equals (n lg n - n + 1); in fact it's between (n lg n - n + 1) and (n lg n + n + O(lg n))

If the first part is true, the second is trivially true as well, but explicitely stating the upper bound seems kind of pointless. I haven't looked at the details myself, but these two statements appear strange when taken together like this. Either the first one really is true, in which case I'd omit the second one as it is only confusing, or the second one is true, in which case the first one is wrong and should be omitted.

Comment: Hi MvG, thanks for your reply. 1st: what you quoted from me is taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort. 2nd: I didn't still get my answer. I wonder why the answer is nlgn-n+1. I think it should be nlogn+n-1 (notice the replacement of + and -), as nlogn is the cost of merge-sort according to the boundary condition and n-1 is the cost of sorting of disordered arrays of n and m (in fact max(n, m)) in the worst case possible (i.e. the first element of n is smaller than that of m, the 2nd element is bigger than that of m and so on). What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Shahin Lists of length 1 are trivially sorted, so there are no comparisons made on the button-most level in the lower bound.

Comment: @Shahin: From your question “what these complexities try to say”, it wasn't clear to me that you were trying to understand where these formulas come from, i.e. how they can be proven. I've added a proof to my answer, hope it is both understandable and correct. Try to be more precise with your questions in the future.