# Finding top and bottom 5 elements of an Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, rank

Question:

I have an array A of n ≥ 10000 distinct positive integers. Trying to write an algorithm that will output one element x of A such that x is not among the top 5 elements of A, neither is it among the bottom 5 elements of A. Top and bottom 5 elements of A are the first 5 and the last 5 elements when A is sorted. Also I need to do this in about 50 comparisons.

What I did:

I am approaching this problem using the concept of Rank.
I take any 6 numbers and find its max. So this will make sure that my number is not among the top(first five) elements. However this does not make sure that my number is not among the last 5 elements.

Pseudocode so far:

//choosing any 6 elements from my Array A.

```
 int max = A[0];
 for(int i = 0; i<6 ; i++)
 {
    if( A[i] > max)
        max = A[i];
 }
```

This will give me one number (max) which would surely not be among first 5 elements of Array but what shall I do about the last 5 elements ?

Comment: are you doing it for the top 5 percent elements or just top 5 and bottom 5 ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could further improve your algorithm by finding, not 6 elements, but 11 random elements (and probably distinct too, if necessary) from the list.

Out of this random 11 elements, sort the elements and pick the 6th element.

The 6th element is necessarily neither among the top 5 nor among the bottom 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care which element to select (only not to be the bottom 5 and top 5), all you can do is to get 11 first elements (you can do anything to select them, even randomly), sort them and take the middle one.

```
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, Yours, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11
```

Even with bubble sort you end up with (11 - 1) * 10 / 2 = 50 comparisons, but with [mergesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346054/number-of-comparisons-in-merge-sort) it will be way less.

Comment: I just understood the problem wrong that she is trying to find among the top 5% element and bottom 5% element. Good Clean solution.