# how many operation is need for sorting?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, decision-tree

**This is a 2016 entrance exam question:**

> We have **N** balls with distinct and unknown weights that have labels **1** to **n**. We are given a two-pan balance and want to use it for weighting these balls in pairs and writing them on a paper in-order to sort all of these balls. *In the worst case, how many weighing operations are need?* Choose the best answer.
>
> a) Ceil[ n log<sub>2</sub> n ]
> b) Floor[ n log<sub>2</sub> n ]
> c) n − 1
> d) Ceil[ log<sub>2</sub> n! ]

According to the answer answer sheet, the correct solution is: Ceil[ log<sub>2</sub> n! ]

My question is: how is this solution is achieved (how does this algorithms work, is there any pesudocode?)?

Comment: Have you tried working out what the correct response is? The solution you have given is also not one of choices (though I think it's d)).

Comment: I correct it sorry @Module

Comment: You think N things can't be sorted because N! is large?  You must realize that can't be correct.  Software sorts N things all the time.m  It's pretty obvious how Bubblesort works, and Bubblesort requires N^2 operations.  The answer to your question is well-known, and you should find it by doing some research, not asking here.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt we can sort n things on at least n log n comparison, isnt it?

Comment: @user355834 Yes. and there are multiple sorting algorithms that can achieve that.

Comment: I couldn't get the point why Ceil[log_2 n!] !!?  @Module

Comment: None of the possible answers is correct: answer (d) assumes there's always an algorithm that sorts in `k` comparisons where `k` is the least integer satisfying `2^k > n!`. But it's far from clear that that's the case, and [OEIS sequence A036604](https://oeis.org/A036604) suggests that `30` comparisons are required in the case `n=12`, while `ceil(log2(n!))` in that case is `29`.

Comment: This bound is not actually achievable. It is only asymptotically correct, but if we were talking about asymptotics, the ceil would be superfluous, and we'd be seeing big-O notation.

Comment: @MarkDickinson you are right very useful. but one sentence I not mentioned is that "choose the best answer." I think with this sentence we can choose "d", isnt it?

Comment: @user2357112 in this question that take from our entrance exam, this is not talking about asymptotic.

Comment: @user355834: There's an obvious and wrong chain of reasoning that leads to answer (d), so it seems likely that the *intended* answer by whomever set the question is (d). But I don't think that makes it the best answer, by any means. In particular, (a) and (b) probably *are* actual upper bounds for the true answer, while (d) is not.

Comment: Sorry if my English usage is not good, (a) and (b) is upper bound but (d) not good as lower bound ? am I right? @MarkDickinson

Comment: Yes, (d) will be a lower bound for the worst-case number of comparisons for any algorithm that solves this problem. It seems *likely* to me that (a) and (b) provide upper bounds, but to show that you'd have to exhibit an actual algorithm that runs with worst case no worse that that given.

Comment: @MarkDickinson because this question says number in the worst case, and say choose the best answer means the lower bound and (d), isn't it?

Comment: @user355834 I am not trying to give you the answer for your homework, but I am glad to see you know that.  My point was simply a response to your remark that you thought no upper bound could exist, because there were too many permutations.

Comment: @MarkDickinson the fewest number of pairwise comparisons needed to sort N=12 is 39:  http://www.angelfire.com/blog/ronz/Articles/999SortingNetworksReferen.html  I agree with you that ceil( log2( N! )) is not correct.  But O( log2( N! )) is.  I would say that the question is mistaken.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: I believe that article is solving a slightly different problem: the basic operation there is a compare-exchange. In the OP's problem, just the comparisons are being counted: arbitrary movements of elements based on the results of those comparisons are permitted.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I can see why you would think that, but the issue is this: suppose you wanted to make an arbitrary movement.  Where would you get the information needed to do that from pairwise comparisons?  It's the same problem.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: No, it really isn't. :-) Note that the table in the article you referenced also has an "Optimal sort" row, with the same values as in the OEIS sequence (so 30 comparisons for the case n=12).

Comment: Which homework? please be polite and honest, I can send you the source link of the old-exam with solution, which homework has solution? // and for your tips, I agree with you, no upper bound I think.

Comment: @MarkDickinson We can wrote the result on a paper as questioner say in the question but no affect the last solution.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt on the link you mentioned the best option is 30 and "MarkDickinson" is right.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [Number of Comparisons in Merge-Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12346054/1468366) you will find my answer there arguing that the total number of comparisons for mergesort (which is known to have good asymptotic behavior) is

> n ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ − 2<sup>⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉</sup> + 1

Of course n ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ = ⌈n log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ and 2<sup>⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉</sup> ≥ n so for n ≥ 1 this confirms answer (a) as an upper bound.

Is (b) a tighter upper bound? If you write ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ = log<sub>2</sub> n + d for some 0 ≤ d < 1 then you get
n (log<sub>2</sub> n + d) − 2<sup>d</sup> n + 1 = n (log<sub>2</sub> n + d − 2<sup>d</sup>) + 1 = (n log<sub>2</sub> n) + n (d − 2<sup>d</sup> + 1/n)
and if you write m := ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ and n = 2<sup>m − d</sup> that last parenthesis becomes (d − 2<sup>d</sup> + 2<sup>d − m</sup>).
[Plotting this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bd-2%5Ed%2B2%5E(d-1),d-2%5Ed%2B2%5E(d-2),d-2%5Ed%2B2%5E(d-3),d-2%5Ed%2B2%5E(d-4)%7D%20for%20d%20from%200%20to%201) for some values of m shows that for integers m ≥ 1 this will *very* likely be zero. You get m = 0 for n = 1, which means d = 0 so the whole parenthesis becomes zero. So when you worked out the details of the proof, this will show that (b) is indeed an upper bound for mergesort.

How about (c)? There is an easy counterexample for n = 3. If you know that ball 1 is lighter than 2 and smaller than 3, this doesn't tell you how to sort 2 and 3. You can show that you can't have chosen a suboptimal algorithm by comparing 1 to both 2 and 3, due to the symmetry of the problem this is a generic situation. So (c) is not an upper bound. Can it be a lower bound? Sure, even to confirm that the balls are already ordered you have to weigh each consecutive pair, resulting in n − 1 comparisons. Even with the best algorithm you can't do better than guessing the correct order and then confirming your guess.

Is (d) a tighter lower bound? [Plots](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bn-1,ld(n!)%7D%20for%20n%20from%200%20to%205) again suggest that it is at least as great as (c), with the exception of a small region with no integer values. So if it is a lower bound, it will be tighter. Now think of a decision tree. Every algorithm to order these n balls can be written as a binary decision tree: you compare two balles named in a given node, and depending on the result of the comparison you proceed with one of two possible next steps. That decision tree has to have n! leafs, since every permutation has to be a distinct leaf so you know the exact permutation once you have reached a leaf. And a binary tree with n! leafs has to have a depth of at least ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n!⌉. So yes, this is a lower bound as well.

Summarizing all of this you have (c) ≤ (d) ≤ x ≤ (b) ≤ (a), where x denotes the number of comparisons an optimal algorithm would need to order all the balls. As a comment by Mark Dickinson pointed out, [A036604 on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A036604) gives explicit lower bounds for some few n, and for n = 12 the inequality (d) < x is strict. So (d) does not describe the optimal algorithm exactly either.

By the way (and to answer your “how does this algorithms work”), finding the optimal algorithm for a given n is fairly easy, at least in theory: compute all possible decision trees for those n! sortings, and choose one with minimal depth. Of course this approach becomes impractical fairly quickly.

Now that we know that none of the answers gives the correct count of the optimal sorting algorithm, which answer is “best”? That depends a lot on context. In many applications, knowing an upper bound to the worst time behavior is more valuable than knowing a lower limit, so (b) would be superior to (d). But apparently the person creating the solution sheet had a different opinion, and went for (d), either because it is closer to the optimum (which I assume but have not proven) or because a lower bound is more useful to the application at hand. If you wanted to, you could likely challenge the whole question on the grounds that “best” wasn't adequately defined in the scope of the question.

Comment: Very nice answer, I think what is the worst case, choose the best answer, means lower bound, isn't it?

Comment: @user355834: I think only the person who set the question can tell you what "best answer" means.

Comment: so 1) if we think that answer sheet is correct, 'd' is correct according to lower bound or at least closer to lower bound, isn't it?  would you please tips me? @MarkDickinson

Comment: number of most operation in worst case is equal to height of decision  tree, that at least has height Ceil[log_2 n!]. get the points @MarkDickinson

Comment: @user355834: I don't have anything to add to MvG's already very thorough answer.

Comment: Please be kind when comes to a beginner person, just you say my argument is true? number of most operation in worst case is equal to height of decision tree, that at least has height Ceil[log_2 n!]. get the points ? @MarkDickinson

Comment: Yes. Worst case number of decisions = height of decision tree, height of decision tree >= ceil(log2(number of leaves)), and number of leaves in this case is n!. So for any (deterministic) algorithm, ceil(log2(n!)) is a lower bound for the worst case weighing operations count of that algorithm. But as MvG points out, a lower bound for the worst case isn't a particularly useful thing to have: you'd  usually want an upper bound.

Comment: very nice question I ask :) thanks so much from your patience @MarkDickinson

Comment: Are you sure n ceil(log n) = ceil(n log n)? In general, a ceil(b) != ceil(ab); for example, 2 ceil(1.5) = 4 and ceil(2 * 1.5) = 3.

Comment: What do you mean @templatetypedef would you please describe a bit more?

Comment: @user355834 I was pointing out a step in the math that looked a bit suspicious. I doubt it breaks anything.

Comment: How your statements affect the solution?! @templatetypedef

Comment: @templatetypedef: You are right, that step is incorrect. Since I still think the tighter bound of (b) is valid (with a bit of hand-weaving where I referred to plots instead of proving a bound), I don't doubt the result but the deduction is flawed. Will see about fixing that.